# Быстрая разработка программ под windows?

Tags: windows, ide, gui

Какие есть языки высокого уровня + удобная среда разработки с визуальным редактором окон, вкладок, различных gui элементов?
Я знаю про дельфи. 
Есть ли еще какие-нибудь аналогичные?

Скажем в дельфи можно быстро сформировать интерфейс и внешний вид программы, двигая элементы gui. 
В php + html + javascript, можно быстро создать сайт, но внешний вид программировать довольно трудно, используя html.

Главное простота языка, скорость его изучения и разработки, наличие готовых библиотек для всех случаев. Чтобы можно было легко создавать окна, вкладки, таблицы двигая их мышкой.
Данные хранятся в базе mysql, нужно очень быстро создать windows программу для запросов в базу, получения результатов, изменения данных, добавления, поиска и.т.д.

Хотелось бы си подобный синтаксис. Если есть событийно-ориентированный язык, как javascript(jquery) то вообще будет супер.

Comment: Qt вас не устраивает?

Comment: C#, например. Можно двигать мышкой, много "готовых библиотек для всех случаев".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писать GUI приложения под Windows можно на многих языках и библиотеках.

Самый актуальный вариант - это использовать связку:

- IDE [Visual Studio 2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (рекомендуется) или [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/)
- Язык C#
- Библиотечки можно скачивать на [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/)
- Оконную библиотеку XAML/WPF (очень похоже на работу с html) или WinForms (сейчас немного устарела).

С помощью [mono](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mono-project.com%2F&ei=H8ybVdCVD8yfsAH3zIroCA&usg=AFQjCNHVts-EqhUHaT4QJLm5yVTUXvWnUA&sig2=_lEdzzZu_o_F7sZ5mEczOQ&bvm=bv.96952980,d.bGg) такие приложения можно будет запускать на Linux и Mac,
но там не будет работать библиотека XAML/WPF. Это нужно учитывать.

Сейчас Microsoft активно взялась за перенос .net на другие платформы.

Из других вариантов:

1. Visual Studio но языки С++/CLI или VB.NET
2. Язык Java
3. [Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)
   и т.д.

Альтернативный подход: https://processing.org/

Comment: не-не, как джавист не могу посоветовать java для быстрого и безболезненного накидывания окошек.

Comment: Берем с перспективой, через 5 лет не захочется тратить время на переучивание... На Джаве пишут... и проблем везде хватает... за их решения платят деньги ;) Но я ж говорю - C#

Comment: Всё что тут перечислили, я знаю и это мне не нравится. 

Среда разработки visual studio перегружена, проще самому код там писать.

1) Есть ли ide, где вся программа перед глазами, чтобы я переключаюсь на вкладку, она отрывается и прямо там двигаю кнопку и это сохраняется. 
2) Чтобы весь лишний код огромный который ide генерирует, где то скрывался и были доступны только высокоуровневые инструменты. А мой код, функции событий gui был бы в отдельных файлах, и я бы видел только мой код, а не сгенерированные тысячи строк?

Comment: В VS так и есть. Отдельный файл для сгенерированного, отдельный для вашего... Можно просто открыть форму и двигать кнопки. Не знаю, что вы там нашли за перегруженность... VS настраивается очень гибко - можно сделать как в notepad...

Comment: Попробуйте https://processing.org/

Answer (score 2):

QtCreator — кроссплатформенная свободная IDE для разработки на С, С++ и QML. Разработана для работы с фреймворком Qt. Включает в себя графический интерфейс отладчика и визуальные средства разработки интерфейса как с использованием QtWidgets, так и QML (аналог WPF).

Comment: Действително Qt на данный момент пожалуй лучший фреймворк для написания GUI приложений, ниже было упомянуто про VS и C#, но если думать о возможности переноса на другие платформы , то у C# (.net) все пока хуже чем у Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Дельфи на C++ - это C++ Builder

Comment: А сколько вакансий на C++ Builder и Delphi на рынке? Будет ли оправдано вложение сил и времени в то, что никому не нужно. C#, Java, Python востребованы

Comment: Вакансий и на дельфи и на билдер хватает, судя по поиску в инете... Причём тут вакансии? Может человек знаком с дельфи и ему нужно просто слабать одну простенькую задачку? На его месте я бы хотя бы глянул на билдер)

Answer (score 1):

В настоящий момент абсолютный лидер [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/vs/community/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ru%2F) (сейчас он бесплатен) + C#. Других альтернатив без костылей и проблем практически нет.